# Android: Custom view for a menu item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, menuitem

I want to be able to specify a custom view for a [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html).

I want to display an indicator on a shopping cart menu item in the action bar displaying how many items are in the cart currently.

Is the only way that I can do this is through adding a custom view instead of utilising the MenuItem lifecycle etc.?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To use a custom view on a [MenuItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html) call [setActionView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29).

You can supply either an already inflated view or a layout resource ID.

Comment: But this woks only on post-Honeycomb api, and what about pre-Honeycomb?

Comment: @FilipZymek for pre-Honeycomb, use [MenuItemCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html) from android support v4 library like this:  MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, R.layout.my_layout);

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this statically? Why do we have to set the view dynamically in our code?

Comment: Because it's a dynamic View. If you want it to have a dynamic layout you can't make it statically.

Comment: @Brad: Every thing works fine but count value is not updating immediately inside fragment, i mean am adding item to cart and increasing count but it is not appearing in custom view,  it is showing previous value... !!