# NavigationDrawer item "notification counters"

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am having a problem with the concept of `NotificationDrawer` item notification numbers. How do I implement this functionality?

Please find the example in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want ?

Comment: Put ListView or RecyclerView under navigation view and you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: check the image i given. now currently i have the navigation drawer items, and what should i code to display the number for the new message? For example, new message comes in, Message will display 1, 2 message come in, will display 2.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Joawzpl   < ---- this is currently my navigation.

Comment: Updated the wording in the question to make it English. @whiterabbit, I understand you may not be a native English speaker, but please take some time to format your questions, as it will be hard for the community to help you otherwise :-)

Comment: need add a new class for the counters?

Answer (score 0):

As the `NavigationView` (Assuming you are using the official Google one) is populated using MenuItems, you can use the same method as you would for those. i.e A custom layout.

[Android: Custom view for a menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332584/android-custom-view-for-a-menu-item)